# Canceling checkbox Check event

Tags: silverlight

There is a checkbox in my form, which is bound two-ways to a boolean value in my model. There is a special case, where the user clicks on the checkbox, is presented a question, and may answer "no". In this case, the action fails, and the checkbox should not be checked.

I have tried with several variations of this, but it won't work, in the sense that the model is correctly set to false, but the checkbox in the UI gets checked anyway.

```
private bool _isName = false;
public bool isName {
  get { return _isName; }
  set {
    if (value && specialCase) {
        if(user answers no)
          value = false;
    }
    _isName = value;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("isName");
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I am hoping you are not actually calling up a user prompt in the middle of your setter... If you are using MVVM that is *all sorts of bad*.

Comment: @HiTechMagic advice accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom `MessageBox` which will get as a parameter cancellation command and command which you will invoke in case user input is positive. Then create two additional methods to `ViewModel` which will be responsible for changing `isName` property. In `xaml` add `EventTrigger` to `CheckBox` on Click event within which show custom MessageBox. Then bind commands that are responsible for changing property to MessageBox.

If you need some code samples or more clarification - I'll provide them.

Comment: So at the core, this involves wiring the Click event.

Comment: You can choose whatever event you want (Checked, Unchecked etc.): [CheckBox Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox_events(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: Using `MessageBox` (or `DialogBox`, whatever we call it) we decoupling ViewModel logic and presentation logic that in core is what we are desiring with MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

OK just to solve the direct problem with that thing, this works:

```
...
if(user answers no) {
  value = false;
  myUiElement.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
              () => { isName = false; }
  };
}
...
```

However as @HiTech Magic suggested, this blatanlty violates sane software principles, so I moved to a more subtle way to violate them.